# can I clear setInterval id again and again

Tags: javascript

I've this statement:

```
var sid = setInterval(...);
```

can I call `clearInterval(sid)` again and again?

if once called clearInterval then no need to call it. But I don't want to maintain a flag for this.

How to implement this logic?

Comment: You can, but it won't do anything - once the interval is cleared once, with `clearInterval`, that'll be enough to keep it from running

Comment: @CertainPerformance how to keep track if the sid has been really cleared? That's my actual question. Should I keep a global flag that will monitor if it has been really cleared?

Comment: If you have called `clearInterval(sid)`, then the interval definitely has really been cleared

Comment: why would you want to call clearInterval more than once for the same id, or do you have multiple setIntervals perhaps?

Comment: Can always change `sid` to a falsy value when you clear it and use  `if(sid)`

Comment: @charlietfl what will happen if I call clearInterval(false)? or clearInterval(0) ? IN that case I'll set sid = 0 after clearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely call it multiple times. It is a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)#Code) when it is called with an interval id that is no longer (or was never) in use:

> If handle does not identify an entry in the list of active timers of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope object on which the method was invoked, the method does nothing.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-clearinterval

Comment: but after clearInterval(sid) won't that sid be reused? Is there guarantee that sid is always ever increasing?

Comment: @user5858 It is guaranteed that ids aren't reused within the lifetime of a `window` object.